# Airpods microphone delay

Tags: audio, microphone

Two year old AirPods, one was water damaged, the other is an eBay replacement. Maybe I'm answering myself with this introduction, but here we go:

They have a 2-4 seconds recording or input delay, that seems to be software mediated (i.e. when recording a voice note, there is a fade-in at the 2-4 seconds mark).
I removed the microphone protection on both sides, tried each side separately, reset them, tried them with my MacBook Pro also. No luck. Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Metaphorically you have a pair of shoes, but one is too small, and the other is missing a heel. You can 'walk' in them, but they just hurt after a while. You've done everything you can to get the AirPods to work, and they appear to have the same problem on more than one device. I'm not sure what more you can do but buy a new pair of shoes. ;-)

Comment: @IconDaemon already did! Thanks for your input!